Using a GIS service to provide a report or summary of municipal zoning information based on user input
The New York State Department of Environmental Conservation (DEC) provides a free online Environmental Assessment Form Mapper, where users create a project site by drawing on the map or select a tax parcel. The online tool then populates a standard form created by the DEC based on the drawn area or selected site.
Here is a link to the tool: https://gisservices.dec.ny.gov/eafmapper/
I am interested in creating a similar tool for zoning data and municipal planning and codes related processes, such as site plan or development review. An example of my goal is providing an online mapping services where users can input their intent for development and the map generates specific feedback based on zoning regulations. Lets pretend I am a homeowner seeking the regulations for constructing a shed in my backyard. On a virtual map, I want to draw the approximate location of the shed on my property, click submit, then have the mapping tool create a popup (or separate form) showing the underlying zoning regulations and how my proposal does (or does not) meet said regulations.
My questions are as follows:
How is the map populating this information based on user input?
Is there a GIS suite of tools already optimized for this use case?
